# Program error in visual studio c++ 2010 express

Tags: c++

May i know how to solve this problem, after i have run my program in visual c++ 2010 express?

**Program Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("Welcome !!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output message**
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Exercise, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Exercise.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1):

Either disable incremental linking, by going to

```
Project Properties 
   -> Configuration Properties 
       -> Linker (General) 
          -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
```

or install VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Why is your entire answer written as if it were a block of code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I will take care next  time. Thanks for pointing out.